# Django template - ajax response - how to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

After reading a bunch of blogs about this i can not find the answer, also searched in SO as well.

I have a template that use django template tags:

```
<div class="box" id="dates">
     <h2 class="h2">Dates</h2>
          <ul class="list-group">
                {% for days in dates %}
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">{{ days }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
          </ul>
</div>
```

This div waits for an answer that comes from an ajax response. Here is the ajax code:

```
$("#formi").submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData($('form').get(0));

        $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"{% url 'dates' %}",
             data: data,
             processData: false,
             contentType: false,
             csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',

             success: function(data){
                 console.log("YEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH")
                 $("#dates").html({{ data.dates }});
                },
        });
   });
```

Pretty self explainatory. It sends a form to a view and the view responds a json with the data that is going to be used to fill the `for loop` in the template.

I can see that the data is getting to the template in th console

[image]

[image]

But as u can see this is not recognizing my `{{data.dates}}` tag after `$("#dates").html`in the ajax succes

So, how can i still use this django tags in my template and get the data out of the ajax response?

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: This is a Gists I did sometime ago, maybe this could help you. Make me know. https://gist.github.com/Gocht/31cc901dbb6fcffa7913

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support such {{ }} template signs. You should just use `...html(data.dates)` and make sure an argument is a string. http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Gocht is exactly right with this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`data` is a plain text, not a python variable so you can't print it out within `{{ }}`. It looks like a JSON object, so you can do the following:

Assuming you have `jQuery` installed:

```
$.each(data.dates, function(i, val) {
    $('ul.list-group').empty().append(
        $('<li>').addClass('list-group-item list-group-item-success').text(val)
    )
});
```

Comment: i see that the dates are appearing now but they lost the class that goes with the <li> tag: `<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">{{ days }}</li>`. Now i see just the text inside a <ul> but no <li> tag. I will mark this as correct cause u actually helped me, i just wan to know if u know how to not lose the class

Comment: If he uses `$.ajax()` he has `Jquery` for sure

Comment: is there a way to add that class to every <li>? with the code u suggested it is only adding the class to one <li> object

Comment: No, it adds those classes to every `<li>`. Can you re-check and confirm?

Comment: I added the last code u provided to the ajax succes: is that ok?. I am seeing that only one date is displayed in the `<ul>`with the correct class, the rest is not appearing at all, and there are 5 dates. If i am cousing to mcuh trouble i can ask another question.

Comment: @ozgur i fixed this problem with help of another response. That u sir

Answer (score 1):

All of the Django templates are rendered as html and js before the page loads, which means that `{{ data.dates }}` will return nothing because you don't have any `data` variable in your python code. Because of that you accept `.html()` in your js code.

`data` is a js object so you can simply do this:

```
$("#dates").html(data.dates);
```

But if you want to keep the old template in the `#dates div` you need to write:

```
var html = "";
$(data.dates).each(function(i, days){
    html += "<li class='list-group-item list-group-item-success'>"+days+"</li>"
});
$("#dates>ul").html(html);
```

Comment: This was awesome, i can not mark it as correct cause @ozgur responded first. But u really helped me with the problem i had with the class