# How to access Queryset returned to template by AJAX response - Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-templates

I want to return a queryset to a template using ajax.

this is my ajax function in a seperate js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#data_to_plot_button").click(function(){
        var serialized_data = $("#data_to_plot_form").serialize();
    
        $.ajax({
            url: $("data_to_plot_form").data('url'),
            data: serialized_data,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(response){
                $("#graph").append('<p>data returned successfuly</p>'); //this line is printed correctly.

                $.each(response, function(i, val) {
                    $('graph').empty().append(
                        $('<li>').addClass('list-group-item list-group-item-success').text(val)
                    )
                }); // this block adds nothing to the #graph div

            }
        })

    });
});
```

and my `views.py`:

```
def my_products(request):
    
    queryset_list_intro_products = Intro_products.objects.all().order_by('title') 

    products = 0 

    if request.method == 'POST':
        products_checkbox = request.POST.get('products')

        if products_checkbox:
            products = serializers.serialize('json', list(queryset_list_intro_products))

        context = {
            'products': products,
        }
        
        return JsonResponse(context, status=200)

    return render(request, 'users/basket/my_products.html')
```

based on an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790538/django-template-ajax-response-how-to), I try to access the returned `products` which is in `response`. but the js code adds nothing to the `#graph` div.

in XHR section of network tab of inspects in chrome, the ajax call's status is 200 and in the preview section I can see the `products` as following:

> products: "[{"model": "products.intro_products", "pk": 5, "fields": {"products_intro": false, "ip_sensor_intro": false, "control_valve_intro": false, "water_quality_sensor_intro": false,  "accessories_intro": true, "cover_intro": "photos/products/intro_cover/solutions.png", "title": "Accessories", "subtitle": "", "description": "
>
> description
>
> ", "detailed_description": "", "video_link": "", "is_published": true, "image_left": "", "title_left": "", "description_left": "", "image_right": "", "title_right": "", "description_right": ""}},

How to access the fields of an ajax response knowing its a queryset?

Comment: Hi, you missed `#` near `$('graph')..`

Comment: @Swati thank you friend, but it didn't help!

Comment: show your excepted output . Also,json which you have added in question is console result ? i.e : `console.log(response)` ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to do something like this;

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

if request.is_ajax():
    html = render_to_string(
        template_name="your seperate template where you want to display the queryset", 
        context=dict_of_items_to_be_passed_to_above_temp.
    )

    data_dict = {"html_from_view": html}

    return JsonResponse(data=data_dict, safe=False)
```

Comment: isnt `request.is_ajax()` deprecatd in django 3.1 ?  and how to use `html` in js file in success function of ajax method?

Comment: I am using the same thing for searching. This works fine. and the data_dict can also be used in js to parse the data.